# Copy all the sub elements of a root element except a given element

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I am new to xslt transformation. I need to print all the sub elements except a given element. This is my xslt:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <statuses>
            <xsl:for-each select="statuses">
                <xsl:variable name='test1' select="status[name='bag']">
                </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:copy-of select="$test1" />
            </xsl:for-each></statuses>
        </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Input XML is mentioned below. The root element is statuses.

```
<statuses>
    <result>name</result>
<count>12</count>
        <status>
            <stockNo>1000</stockNo>
            <itemNo>500</itemNo>
            <name>frock</name>
        </status>
<status>
                <stockNo>1000</stockNo>
                <itemNo>500</itemNo>
                <name>bag</name>
            </status>
<gage>3</gage>
</statuses>
```

I need to print all the 'status' elements of 'bag' with all other elements as it is.  Without frock type or any other type of status except bag. I'd appreciate if you can help me to write the xslt to fulfil my requirement.
The output XML is mentioned below. Statuses, result, count, filtered status, page should be printed.

```
<statuses>
        <result>name</result>
    <count>12</count>
    <status>
                    <stockNo>1000</stockNo>
                    <itemNo>500</itemNo>
                    <name>bag</name>
                </status>
    <gage>3</gage>
</statuses>
```

Comment: this is my output.    <statuses>
            <result>name</result>
        <count>12</count>
        <status>
                        <stockNo>1000</stockNo>
                        <itemNo>500</itemNo>
                        <name>bag</name>
                    </status>
        <gage>3</gage>
    </statuses>

Comment: Please add your output in the question by editing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**XSLT 1.0**

I am not sure if I understood you. But if the xml you want to get is the one in the end of your post, you can use:

```
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template match="status" >

        <xsl:if test="name = 'bag'">
            <status>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </status>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This should reprint your xml document without any status elements whose name is not bag.

Answer (score 0):

Or simply:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node() except status[name!='bag']"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Or, if you're using XSLT 1.0, as you apparently do (despite having tagged your question as XSLT 2.0):

```
<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[not(self::status[name!='bag'])]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: thank very much for the reply. but this is not filtering. i got all the status elements including 'frock'.

Comment: yes apparently it works in your test tool. but for my tool it did not worked. i think it is a xsl version issue. I'm using xsl 1.0.

Comment: @rojaderman- at that moment i used xsl 1.0 version. i did not think about it. After only i realized tools support for different versions. but not for all versions.